# socket.io.js not found using (express [4.13] + socket.io[1.3]) in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express, express-generator

I am using express 4.13 and socket.io 1.3.2 with express generator

Below is my code in app.js

```
var app = express();
var  server=require('http').createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),'127.0.0.1');
var io=require('socket.io')(server);
```

My Client side code :

```
var socket=io.connect("http://localhost:3000");
```

but still i get http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js not found . I tried many online solutions many of them are for express 3.*.I am totally new in nodejs so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try [solution from socket.io docs](http://socket.io/docs/#using-with-express-3/4), but replace port 80 to 3000

Comment: Already using port 3000 also tried with port 8080 still same result.

Comment: Is script serving at `http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js` after server started? How do you include socket.io lib on clientside? Try this `<script src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`